# Laravel 5.2 Socialite Facebook API login redirect error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My Facebook login has suddenly stopped working using the Socialite package with Laravel 5.2. I have had it fully functional for a few days now and it just seems to of dropped off. I am fairly new to Laravel so please have some grace if it is something easy.

I get this error:

***"The www.facebook.com page isn’t working. www.facebook.com redirected you too many times."***

I have tried restarting the local server, running commands like `php artisan config:clear`. Also tried installing with composer running version `"laravel/socialite": "^2.0"`. I can't help but think it is something actually in the Facebook Developer Apps API config but everything looks okay!

I will provide my code just in case anyone who has the time to help and can spot any bugs. I used this link as a guide to go off https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.WK8bGBKLRBw

**.env**

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxx
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxxx
FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('auth/facebook',  'Auth\FacebookController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback',  'Auth\FacebookController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**FacebookController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\SocialAccountService;
use Socialite;


class FacebookController extends Controller
{

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {

       //send off a request and to FB and get a token
       return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();

    }

    public function handleProviderCallback(SocialAccountService $service)
    {

        $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('facebook')->user());

        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect()->to('account/{id}/myaccount');
    }
}
```

**SocialAccountService.php**

```
namespace App;

use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\User as ProviderUser;

class SocialAccountService
{
    public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser)
    {

        $account = SocialAccount::whereProvider('facebook')
            ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
            ->first();

        if ($account) {
            return $account->user;
        } else {

            $account = new SocialAccount([
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => 'facebook'
            ]);

            $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

            if (!$user) {

                $user = User::create([
                    'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                    'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                ]);
            }

            $account->user()->associate($user);
            $account->save();

            return $user;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right guys, if anyone is facing issues like this I can be fairly certain that your routes or callback URL is slightly incorrect, either within your `developers.facebook.com` account or your `.env` file config. In my case in my `.env` I had my callback with an additional trailing `'/'`.

Causing the redirect issue:

`FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/`

Fixed the redirect issue:

```
FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook
```

The callback from Facebook appends `'/callback?code=xxxxYOUR-TOKENxxxxxx'`

So with that extra `'/'` it seemed to be confusing the callback causing the redirect loop.